# Semantics for de Bruijn levels

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

There is an exceptionally simple way to embed simply typed lambda calculus with de Bruijn indices in a functional host language (discussed by [Carette, Kiselyov & Shan](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/JFP.pdf), and by [Kiselyov](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/course/lecture.pdf)). The construction here, expressed in Haskell, is from Kiselyov's paper:

```hs
z :: (a, b) -> a
z (x, _) = x

s :: (a -> b) -> (c, a) -> b
s v (_, h) = v h

lam :: ((a, b) -> c) -> b -> a -> c
lam e h x = e (x, h)

app :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
app e1 e2 h = e1 h (e2 h)

eval :: (() -> a) -> a
eval e = e ()
```

So, for example `eval (lam (lam (app z (s z)))) 2 succ` evaluates to `3`, as our `lam` expression `eval`'s to the Haskell value `\x -> \f -> f x`.

This embedding uses de Bruijn *indices*: to find the binder of a variable, count upward from the variable. I am curious about whether there is an analogous embedding of de Bruijn *levels*, where to find a variable's binder we count *downward*. Concretely, `\x -> \f -> f x` would be represented in such an embedding as `lam' (lam' (app' (s' z') z'))`.

The above embedding uses (as Kiselyov notes) nothing beyond the Hindley-Milner subset of Haskell 2010. It is not obvious to me whether de Bruijn levels can be implemented in such a simple type system. Indeed, it seems quite difficult: the environment tuples built by `lam` would need to be turned inside-out, or our variables would need to behave differently depending on the depth of the environment tuple. If we only had variables of one type, we could use lists; given that our variables have multiple types, do we require `HList`s?

======

Late edit to expand on the points in the last paragraph...

One way to think about de Bruijn levels is that `lam` `append`'s (rather than `cons`'s) to the environment. This way, from the perspective of a variable, the `head` of the environment (in a closed term) will always correspond to the highest `lam`. In terms of homogeneous lists:

```hs
zL :: [a] -> a
zL (x:h) = x

sL :: ([a] -> b) -> [a] -> b
sL v (_:h) = v h

lamL :: ([a] -> b) -> [a] -> a -> b
lamL e h x = e (h++[x])

appL :: ([a] -> b -> c) -> ([a] -> b) -> [a] -> c
appL e1 e2 h = e1 h (e2 h)

evalL :: ([a] -> b) -> b
evalL e = e []
```

This models de Bruijn levels, in the sense that `lamL (lamL (sL zL)) [] 2 3` evaluates to `3`. But it isn't simply typed lambda calculus, since it only allows variables of one type -- e.g., `lamL (lamL (appL (sL zL) zL))` is a type error.

To allow variables of multiple types, we can use [`HList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-HList-HList.html):

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

import Data.HList

zH :: HList (a ': b) -> a
zH (HCons x h) = x

sH :: (HList a -> b) -> HList (c ': a) -> b
sH v (HCons _ h) = v h

lamH :: HAppendList a '[b] =>
        (HList (HAppendListR a '[b]) -> c) -> HList a -> b -> c
lamH e h x = e (hAppendList h (HCons x HNil))

appH :: (HList a -> b -> c) -> (HList a -> b) -> HList a -> c
appH e1 e2 h = e1 h (e2 h)
```

Then `lamH (lamH (appH (sH zH) zH)) HNil 2 succ` evaluates to `3`, as desired. But this is a significantly heavier-duty approach than the embedding we began with. Do de Bruijn levels require all this artillery?

Comment: Is the question: can de Bruijn levels be implemented in Haskell 10? or can de Bruijn levels be implemented more simply than with your type family approach? I believe the answer to the first is no.

Comment: Both sorts of answers would be helpful, though the question is not about Haskell per se, but what kind of type theory is required to give a denotational semantics for de Bruijn levels.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a provisional answer. The de Bruijn index and level of a bound variable sum up to the number of enclosing lambdas: $i+l=n_\lambda$. Since the index can be recovered from the level by subtraction, levels can be implemented as 'predecessor' indices `p`:

```
z :: (a, b) -> a
z (x, _) = x

s :: (a -> b) -> (c, a) -> b
s v (_, h) = v h

-- ^^^ as above

p :: (((), a) -> b) -> a -> b
p v h = v ((), h)

-- (p . s) v == v

app :: (a -> b -> c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d
app e1 e2 v h = e1 v h (e2 v h)

-- app manages an extra bit of context: the number of enclosing lambdas

lam :: (((a, b) -> c) -> (d, e) -> f) ->
       (b -> c) -> e -> d -> f
lam e v h x = e (s v) (x, h)

-- lam increments that context

eval :: (((a, env) -> a) -> () -> b) -> b
eval t = t z ()

-- evaluating closed terms...the starting context is z
```

This seems reasonable, and terms with just one variable (and arbitrary numbers of lambdas) behave as expected. But the type-checker chokes on terms with distinct variables -- e.g., `app (p . p) p`, our representation of the open term $21$, gives an 'infinite type' error.

To see why, let's consider a concrete evaluated closed term, `eval $ lam (lam (app (p . p) p))`. If you churn through the reductions by hand, eventually you end up with the following:

```
\x f -> s (s z) ((), ((), (f, (x, ())))) (s (s z) ((), (f, (x, ()))))
```

If both occurrences of `s (s z)` are polymorphic, this appears well-typed, and can be further simplified, to `\x f -> f x`, as desired (well, our de Bruijn level representation of this term is $\lambda\lambda 21$... close enough!). The problem, it seems, is that the Haskell type-checker insists that the two occurrences of `s (s z)` have the same monomorphic type, and therefore seems related to the absence of 'first-class polymorphism' in Haskell.

It is not obvious to me how 'deep' the problem here goes -- whether it can be massaged in Haskell; and if not, whether the implementation here can be coherently stated in, e.g., System F (Hindley-Milner seems out due to the need for first-class polymorphism).